# Graphql shield returns Not Authorised Error

Tags: graphql, typeorm, apollo-server

I am using graphql shield to create permission layers for my application. I have not added any rules for my resolvers yet. I have an issue that whenever I throw a custom error in my resolver I get not Authorized rather than the custom error that is thrown within the resolver.

```
import { allow, deny, not, shield } from 'graphql-shield';
import { isAuthenticated } from './rules/isAuthenticated';

export const permissions = shield({
    Query: {},
    Mutation: {},
});
 const schemaWithPermissions = applyMiddleware(schema, permissions);

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema: schemaWithPermissions,
        context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
    });



   @Mutation(() => String)
    testResolver() {
        throw new Error('An error occurred');
    
        return 'hello';
    }
I believe that if an error is thrown here, I should get the custom 'An error occurred message' which is contrary to what am getting 'Not Authorized'
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, graphql-shield intercepts all errors thrown during resolver execution. This ensures that any internal logic or sensitive information is not exposed to the client unintentionally. https://the-guild.dev/graphql/shield/docs/errors

```
@Mutation(() => String)
    testResolver() {
        //return error
        return Error('An error occurred');
    
        return 'hello';
    }
s
```